# Is ISTIO internal traffic routing possible with custom gateway?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, istio, azure-application-gateway

Is ISTIO internal traffic routing to different versions possible even when I use custom gateways? (Azure App gateway). Below is my use case. I have two different versions of deployments (Kubernetes) with the labels `app:myapp` & `version: v1` and `version: v2` [v1 label for one deployment and v2 label for another]. The traffic is currently evenly distributed between these two and the same can be seen in kiali dashboard too. I want to route traffic only to `v2`. Below are my virtual service and destination rules.

**VIRTUAL SERVICE:**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: myvirtualservice
  namespace: mynamespace # Use same namespace with backend service
spec:
  hosts:
  - myservice.namespace.svc.cluster.local
  ingress:
  - appgw # define ingress name
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 80 # Backend service port
        host: myservice.namespace.svc.cluster.local # Backend service name
        subset: v2
```

**DESTINATION RULE:**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: mydestrule
spec:
  host: myservice.namespace.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
```

Currently in the kiali dashboard too my azure ingress gateway is shown as "unknown" resource.

Answer (score 1):

If I see it correctly you are missing the subset selector in the Destination of the VirtualService.
If you configure the VirtualService like this it should work better:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: myvirtualservice
  namespace: mynamespace # Use same namespace with backend service
spec:
  hosts:
  - myservice.namespace.svc.cluster.local
  ingress:
  - appgw # define ingress name
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 80
        host: myservice.namespace.svc.cluster.local 
        subset: v2 # <- Route to the subset v2 and enable endpoint select by label
```

See https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#Destination

Comment: Tried that too. Didn't workout. Request is still flowing to both deployments. Actually I had tried it before itself. Missed out on the question, Now I have updated it in the question too.

Comment: Is the DestinationRule in the same namespace? It has to be in the namespace of the Service or istio-system to be applied to a Gateway

Comment: Panzer Yes it is present in the same namespace.

Comment: This is possible. Tested with the istio provided bookinfo app. But it's not working for me. Even tried creating Virtual service from the kiali dashboard itself. Still no luck. Don't know where I'm going wrong.